# Binary Search Tree failing left rotation

Tags: java, testing, rotation, binary-search-tree

All of my tests pass for my Binary Search tree rotation program except when gradescope runs a left test rotation. The data used is creating a search tree with level order: 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7 to be rotated around 4 and 2 and the level order result expected: 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7 but on my IDE I got 2, 1, 3 which I assume set some nodes into null. I think there is something wrong with my left rotation algorithm but I am not really sure what it is. Any ideas?

`

```
// --== CS400 Rotation Implementation Activity File Header ==--
// Name: Arber Jonuzi
// CSL Username: arber
// Email: akjonuzi@wisc.edu
// Lecture #: 003 @2:25pm
// Notes to Grader: N/A



import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Red-Black Tree implementation with a Node inner class for representing
 * the nodes of the tree. Currently, this implements a Binary Search Tree that
 * we will turn into a red black tree by modifying the insert functionality.
 * In this activity, we will start with implementing rotations for the binary
 * search tree insert algorithm. You can use this class' insert method to build
 * a regular binary search tree, and its toString method to display a level-order
 * traversal of the tree.
 */
public class RedBlackTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    /**
     * This class represents a node holding a single value within a binary tree
     * the parent, left, and right child references are always maintained.
     */
    protected static class Node<T> {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> parent; // null for root node
        public Node<T> leftChild;
        public Node<T> rightChild;
        public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }
        /**
         * @return true when this node has a parent and is the left child of
         * that parent, otherwise return false
         */
        public boolean isLeftChild() {
            return parent != null && parent.leftChild == this;
        }
        
        public boolean isRightChild() {
            return parent != null && parent.rightChild == this;
        }

    }

    protected Node<T> root; // reference to root node of tree, null when empty
    protected int size = 0; // the number of values in the tree

    /**
     * Performs a naive insertion into a binary search tree: adding the input
     * data value to a new node in a leaf position within the tree. After  
     * this insertion, no attempt is made to restructure or balance the tree.
     * This tree will not hold null references, nor duplicate data values.
     * @param data to be added into this binary search tree
     * @return true if the value was inserted, false if not
     * @throws NullPointerException when the provided data argument is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException when the newNode and subtree contain
     *      equal data references
     */
    public boolean insert(T data) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
        // null references cannot be stored within this tree
        if(data == null) throw new NullPointerException(
                "This RedBlackTree cannot store null references.");

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(data);
        if(root == null) { root = newNode; size++; return true; } // add first node to an empty tree
        else{
            boolean returnValue = insertHelper(newNode,root); // recursively insert into subtree
            if (returnValue) size++;
            else throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "This RedBlackTree already contains that value.");
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursive helper method to find the subtree with a null reference in the
     * position that the newNode should be inserted, and then extend this tree
     * by the newNode in that position.
     * @param newNode is the new node that is being added to this tree
     * @param subtree is the reference to a node within this tree which the 
     *      newNode should be inserted as a descenedent beneath
     * @return true is the value was inserted in subtree, false if not
     */
    private boolean insertHelper(Node<T> newNode, Node<T> subtree) {
        int compare = newNode.data.compareTo(subtree.data);
        // do not allow duplicate values to be stored within this tree
        if(compare == 0) return false;

            // store newNode within left subtree of subtree
        else if(compare < 0) {
            if(subtree.leftChild == null) { // left subtree empty, add here
                subtree.leftChild = newNode;
                newNode.parent = subtree;
                return true;
                // otherwise continue recursive search for location to insert
            } else return insertHelper(newNode, subtree.leftChild);
        }

        // store newNode within the right subtree of subtree
        else {
            if(subtree.rightChild == null) { // right subtree empty, add here
                subtree.rightChild = newNode;
                newNode.parent = subtree;
                return true;
                // otherwise continue recursive search for location to insert
            } else return insertHelper(newNode, subtree.rightChild);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs the rotation operation on the provided nodes within this tree.
     * When the provided child is a leftChild of the provided parent, this
     * method will perform a right rotation. When the provided child is a
     * rightChild of the provided parent, this method will perform a left rotation.
     * When the provided nodes are not related in one of these ways, this method
     * will throw an IllegalArgumentException.
     * @param child is the node being rotated from child to parent position
     *      (between these two node arguments)
     * @param parent is the node being rotated from parent to child position
     *      (between these two node arguments)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException when the provided child and parent
     *      node references are not initially (pre-rotation) related that way
     */
    private void rotate(Node<T> child, Node<T> parent) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        
        //right rotation
        if(child == parent.leftChild) {
            
            Node<T> left = null;
            if(child.rightChild != null) {
            left = child.rightChild;}
            
            if(parent.isRightChild()) {
                parent.parent.rightChild=child;
            }
            
            parent.leftChild = left;
            
            parent.parent = child;
            child.parent = parent.parent;
            child.rightChild = parent;
            
            if(parent == root) {
                child.parent = null;
                root = child;
            }
            

        }
        
        //left rotation
        else if(child == parent.rightChild) {
            
            Node<T> left = null;
            if(child.leftChild!=null) {
            left = child.leftChild;}
            

            if(parent.isLeftChild()) {
                parent.parent.leftChild=child;
            }
            
            parent.rightChild = left;
            
            parent.parent = child;
            child.parent = parent.parent;
            child.leftChild = parent;
            
        }
        
        //exception
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong left and right child");
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the size of the tree (its number of nodes).
     * @return the number of nodes in the tree
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if the tree is empty (does not contain any node).
     * @return true of this.size() return 0, false if this.size() > 0
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the tree contains the value *data*.
     * @param data the data value to test for
     * @return true if *data* is in the tree, false if it is not in the tree
     */
    public boolean contains(T data) {
        // null references will not be stored within this tree
        if(data == null) throw new NullPointerException(
                "This RedBlackTree cannot store null references.");
        return this.containsHelper(data, root);
    }

    /**
     * Recursive helper method that recurses through the tree and looks
     * for the value *data*.
     * @param data the data value to look for
     * @param subtree the subtree to search through
     * @return true of the value is in the subtree, false if not
     */
    private boolean containsHelper(T data, Node<T> subtree) {
        if (subtree == null) {
            // we are at a null child, value is not in tree
            return false;
        } else {
            int compare = data.compareTo(subtree.data);
            if (compare < 0) {
                // go left in the tree
                return containsHelper(data, subtree.leftChild);
            } else if (compare > 0) {
                // go right in the tree
                return containsHelper(data, subtree.rightChild);
            } else {
                // we found it :)
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method performs an inorder traversal of the tree. The string 
     * representations of each data value within this tree are assembled into a
     * comma separated string within brackets (similar to many implementations 
     * of java.util.Collection, like java.util.ArrayList, LinkedList, etc).
     * Note that this RedBlackTree class implementation of toString generates an
     * inorder traversal. The toString of the Node class class above
     * produces a level order traversal of the nodes / values of the tree.
     * @return string containing the ordered values of this tree (in-order traversal)
     */
    public String toInOrderString() {
        // generate a string of all values of the tree in (ordered) in-order
        // traversal sequence
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("[ ");
        sb.append(toInOrderStringHelper("", this.root));
        if (this.root != null) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        }
        sb.append(" ]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String toInOrderStringHelper(String str, Node<T> node){
        if (node == null) {
            return str;
        }
        str = toInOrderStringHelper(str, node.leftChild);
        str += (node.data.toString() + ", ");
        str = toInOrderStringHelper(str, node.rightChild);
        return str;
    }

    /**
     * This method performs a level order traversal of the tree rooted
     * at the current node. The string representations of each data value
     * within this tree are assembled into a comma separated string within
     * brackets (similar to many implementations of java.util.Collection).
     * Note that the Node's implementation of toString generates a level
     * order traversal. The toString of the RedBlackTree class below
     * produces an inorder traversal of the nodes / values of the tree.
     * This method will be helpful as a helper for the debugging and testing
     * of your rotation implementation.
     * @return string containing the values of this tree in level order
     */
    public String toLevelOrderString() {
        String output = "[ ";
        if (this.root != null) {
            LinkedList<Node<T>> q = new LinkedList<>();
            q.add(this.root);
            while(!q.isEmpty()) {
                Node<T> next = q.removeFirst();
                if(next.leftChild != null) q.add(next.leftChild);
                if(next.rightChild != null) q.add(next.rightChild);
                output += next.data.toString();
                if(!q.isEmpty()) output += ", ";
            }
        }
        return output + " ]";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "level order: " + this.toLevelOrderString() +
                "\nin order: " + this.toInOrderString();
    }

    
    // Implement at least 3 boolean test methods by using the method signatures below,
    // removing the comments around them and addind your testing code to them. You can
    // use your notes from lecture for ideas on concrete examples of rotation to test for.
    // Make sure to include rotations within and at the root of a tree in your test cases.
    // If you are adding additional tests, then name the method similar to the ones given below.
    // Eg: public static boolean test4() {}
    // Do not change the method name or return type of the existing tests.
    // You can run your tests by commenting in the calls to the test methods 

    //pass
    public static boolean test1() {
        
        RedBlackTree test = new RedBlackTree();
        
        try {
            test.insert(1);
            test.insert(10);
            test.insert(16);
            test.insert(43);
            test.insert(6);
            test.insert(11);
            test.insert(18);
            test.rotate(test.root.rightChild.rightChild.leftChild, test.root.rightChild.rightChild);
            System.out.println(test.toString());
            
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }
    

    //pass
    public static boolean test2() {
        RedBlackTree test = new RedBlackTree();
        
        try {
            test.insert(4);
            test.insert(2);
            test.insert(6);
            test.insert(1);
            test.insert(3);
            test.insert(5);
            test.insert(7);
            test.rotate(test.root.rightChild.leftChild, test.root.rightChild );
            System.out.println(test.toString());
            
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
         
        return true;
    }
    

    //tests  null exception
    public static boolean test3() {
    
        RedBlackTree test = new RedBlackTree();
        
        try {
            test.insert(14);
            test.insert(32);
            test.insert(46);
            test.insert(15);
            test.insert(34);
            test.insert(55);
            test.insert(37);
            test.rotate(test.root.leftChild.rightChild, test.root.leftChild );
            System.out.println(test.toString());
            
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }
    
    //pass
    public static boolean test4() {
        RedBlackTree test = new RedBlackTree();
        
        try {
            test.insert(2);
            test.insert(1);
            test.insert(4);
            test.insert(3);
            test.insert(6);
            test.insert(5);
            test.insert(7);
            test.rotate(test.root.rightChild, test.root);
            System.out.println(test.toString());
            
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
         
        return true;
    }
    

    /**
     * Main method to run tests. Comment out the lines for each test
     * to run them.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("Test 1 passed: " + test1());
        // System.out.println("Test 2 passed: " + test2());
        // System.out.println("Test 3 passed: " + test3());
         System.out.println("Test 4 passed: " + test4());
    }

}
```

`

I have tried creating other test cases to confirm and the left rotation still seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is in your left rotation logic. When doing a left rotation, the key steps are:

The right child of the child node becomes the left child of the parent node.
The parent node becomes the right child of the child node.
Update the parent pointers accordingly.
Handle special cases like the parent node being the root etc.
Looking at your code, it seems you are missing step 1 where you need to set the right child of the child as the left child of the parent.

Here is what the left rotation logic could look like:

```
//left rotation 
else if(child == parent.rightChild) {

  Node<T> left = child.leftChild;
  
  parent.rightChild = left;
  
  child.leftChild = parent;
  parent.parent = child;

  if(child.parent == null) {
    root = child;
  }
  else {
    // Update parent pointer of child
    if(child.isLeftChild()) {
      child.parent.leftChild = child;
    } else {
      child.parent.rightChild = child; 
    }
  }

  child.parent = parent. Parent;

}
```